# Unit Testing Javascript Code Inlined Within PHP

Tags: php, javascript, unit-testing

At work I've been tasked with unit testing our Javascript code. I settled upon the Jasmine unit testing framework and began to learn how to use it when I was informed that we were now inline our Javascript code within PHP and not even using Javascript files any longer.

Can Jasmine work around this? Is there another framework that could? Should I be using a PHP unit test and a Javascript unit test? What would be my best approach?

Some example code from a fairly basic page to give you an idea:

http://pastebin.com/K3YP33id

http://pastebin.com/QaR8zUh1 <---submit

any sort of insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That's a tough spot to be in (in there myself). IMO, you really need to test both, for the JS you probably need something like PhantomJS to test the actual JavaScript output from the HTTP Request.

Comment: *"we were now inline our Javascript code within PHP and not even using Javascript files any longer."* ... wow ... who thought that was a good idea????

Comment: Aknosis - I'll look into PhantomJS and a PHP Unit Testing framework, thanks for your response!

Comment: rdlowrey- It seems like a couple people around the office have been saying this! Everything seems to be working ok outside of this issue so far though.

Comment: It would be one thing if this were inline JavaScript....  So rather then just load the JavaScript file, it appears there is now a PHP file that has HTML + JavaScript concatenated together, and then returned in a JSON response.   I'm assuming for purposes of an AJAX call to load the page content...   That, and the littering of getCmp() calls, is annoying...   I'm going to run-down-the-hall screaming now, because I have sympathy pains.

Comment: In this scenario (assuming you can't change the DEVs minds), I'd make sure the Developers are validating their JavaScript code with JSL (JavaScript Lint), and then just setup some thorough regression tests using Selenium (automated testing using web browser, I prefer Perl's WWW Selenium Module, etc.).   With decisions like the ones you mention, I'd stay away from official Unit testing, because there might be too much chaos there to 'keep up with'.  If you concentrate on the UI behavior, you should just have to respond to UI and enhancement changes, rather then other cruft.

Comment: We've decided to split the PHP and Javascript, a prudent decision I'd say :)

Thank you for the input JMC!

Comment: Just an idea, you could always try to do functional testing with Selenium ... maybe. You can send Javascript directly to the browser and test the values back. I'm not a pro, however. This was just an idea.

Comment: This type of practice is why PHP gets a bad rap lol. BTW if for some reason you did need to have the JS in PHP & between script tags instead of referenced by src, you could do something like $jscode = '<script type="text/javascript">'.file_get_contents('path/to/file.js').'</script>'; to achieve the same effect as the ManageVehicleRates example shown while keeping js in its own file. The only legitimate use for JS embedded in PHP is if you need to use PHP variables in the JS code itself, and even then there is usually a better way to go about that...

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to split all PHP out of javascript and Unit test each separately.  In the long run, it becomes a nightmare to maintain and test heavily integrated code.  Try a modularize as much as possible.

For example, here's how I would do it:

```
var exampleVariables = {
    'name' = <?=$name?>,
    'occupation' = <?=$occupation?>
};

unitTestableFunction(exampleVariables);
```